# Node.js, хранение и обработка большой информации

Tags: база-данных, node.js

У меня на **Node.js** реализован веб сервер, который хранит постоянно пополняющуюся информацию. Сейчас информация хранится в обычном *.json* файле и работа производится обычным `require('fs')`

Как и следует ожидать, через некоторое время происходят ошибки и тд, и в конечном итоге вся информация теряется и приходится пополнять её снова.

Как правильно и лучше всего работать с данными на **Node.js**, чтобы после "падения" сервера, можно было просто его включить и последние данные подгружались.

Comment: Для хранения информации человечество придумало базы данных. Начиная с классических SQL-ных (MySQL, Postgres, sqlite) и всяких noSQL (Mondo, Redis и т.п.)

Comment: "через некоторое время происходят ошибки и тд, и в конечном итоге вся информация теряется и приходится пополнять её снова" - причины неизвестны?

Answer (score 1):

Есть небольшой ответ в комментарии, но я вам приведу текст описания метки [база-данных](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85). Ведь по сути описание метки подходит в качестве ответа. Где хранить данные, если их много, чтобы была сохранена целостность, а также после падения сервера просто все протсо включить - да, однозначно вам нужна база данных. Ознакомиться с ним вы всегда могли вот тут: [Информация о метке база-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/info).

> База данных — это структурированное хранилище однотипных данных. База данных – это информационная модель, позволяющая упорядоченно хранить данные о группе объектов, обладающих одинаковым набором свойств.
>   Как правило, эксплуатируется реляционная модель данных, основанная на
>   теории множеств и логике первого порядка, хотя существуют и
>   нереляционные БД для задач, в которых применение реляционной БД
>   неоправданно.
>
> База данных обеспечивает целостность, извлечение, редактирование,
>   добавление, разграничение прав доступа для данных, позволяет явно
>   указывать отношения между ними и т. д. Основной общепринятый стандарт
>   для реляционных БД — ANSI SQL 92.

**Список популярных СУБД**

- [4D](http://www.4d.com)
- [Apache CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org) [couchdb](/questions/tagged/couchdb)
- [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) [derby](/questions/tagged/derby)
- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org) [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra)
- [HBase](https://hbase.apache.org) [hbase](/questions/tagged/hbase)
- [IBM Informix](http://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/technology/informix/)
- [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org) [mariadb](/questions/tagged/mariadb)
- [Microsoft Office Access](http://microsoftaccess.com/) [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access)
- [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com) [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb)
- [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)
- [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com) [neo4j](/questions/tagged/neo4j)
- [Oracle Database](https://www.oracle.com/database/index.html) [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org) [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql)
- [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/default.aspx) [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server)
- [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org) [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite)
- [Sybase Database Management](http://www.sybase.com/) [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase)

P.S.: **СУБД - система управления базами данных**